# How do I redirect to a different form in a _custom_access routing call

Tags: routes, redirection

In my D10 application, it is required that I have a parallel user login system separate from the Drupal system (it is a requirement I cannot change). On my routing, I have the following:

```
msul_tgif_star_xml_client.login:
  path: '/tgif/login'
  defaults:
    _title: 'TGIF Login'
    _form: 'Drupal\msul_tgif_star_xml_client\Form\LoginForm'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'

msul_tgif_star_xml_client.somepage:
  path: '/somepath'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\msul_tgif_star_xml_client\Form\SomeRandomForm'
  requirements:                                                              
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\msul_tgif_star_xml_client\securityCheck::access'

msul_tgif_star_xml_client.someotherpage:
  path: '/somepath/other'
  defaults:
    _form: '\Drupal\msul_tgif_star_xml_client\Form\SomeotherRandomForm'
  requirements:                                                              
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\msul_tgif_star_xml_client\securityCheck::access'
```

For the access function I have:

```
final class securityCheck {
  public function access(AccountInterface $account, Request $request)
  {
    // Do some security checking based on factors such as IP address, tokens, etc.
    if($checkOK){
      return AccessResult::allowedIf($checkOK);
    }
    else{
      return new RedirectResponse(
                      \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute(
                        'msul_tgif_star_xml_client.login')
                      ->toString()
                 );
    }
  }
}
```

This does not work, of course, because the _access_callback demands a return type of AccessResult.  How do I make the else clause redirect to the login form from the access callback?

Comment: Access callbacks can only determine access, literally nothing else - what you're describing is typically a controller (or middleware)'s job

Comment: A negative AccessResult throws an AccessDeniedHttpException which can be caught in a kernel exception subscriber. Here you can set a redirect response, either depending on the route name or, if you want it more specific, give a reason in the returned access result and check this in the AccessDeniedHttpException when handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return an access result, for example:

```
return AccessResult::forbidden('Redirect me!');
```

This results in an access denied exception, which you can catch in an exception subscriber:

*src/EventSubscriber/MymoduleExceptionSubscriber.php*

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber;

use Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\HttpExceptionSubscriberBase;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ExceptionEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\AccessDeniedHttpException;

class MymoduleExceptionSubscriber extends HttpExceptionSubscriberBase {

  protected function getHandledFormats() {
    return ['html'];
  }

  public function on403(ExceptionEvent $event) {
    $exception = $event->getThrowable();
    if ($exception instanceof AccessDeniedHttpException) {
      if ($exception->getMessage() == 'Redirect me!') {
        $response = new RedirectResponse('/different/login');
        $event->setResponse($response);
      }
    }
  }

}
```

*mymodule.services.yml*

```
services:
  mymodule.403_subscriber:
    class: Drupal\mymodule\EventSubscriber\MymoduleExceptionSubscriber
    tags:
      - { name: event_subscriber }
```